# Multithreaded cv2.imshow() in Python does not work

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I have two cameras (using OpenNI, I have two streams per camera, handled by the same instance of the driver API) and would like to have two threads, each capturing data from each camera independently, i.e. for one instance of the driver API, say `cam_handler`, I have two streams `depth` and `rgb` per camera, say `cam_handler.RGB1_stream` and `cam_handler.DEPTH1_stream`

Here is the code for the same:

```
import threading

def capture_and_save(cam_handle, cam_id, dir_to_write, log_writer, rgb_stream,
                     depth_stream, io):
    t = threading.currentThread()
    shot_idx = 0
    rgb_window = 'RGB' + str(cam_id)
    depth_window = 'DEPTH' + str(cam_id)
    while getattr(t, "do_run", True):
        if rgb_stream is not None:

            rgb_array = cam_handle.get_rgb(rgb_stream)
            rgb_array_disp = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2.imshow(rgb_window, rgb_array_disp)
            cam_handle.save_frame('rgb', rgb_array, shot_idx, dir_to_write + str(cam_id + 1))
            io.write_log(log_writer[cam_id], shot_idx, None)

        if depth_stream is not None:
            depth_array = cam_handle.get_depth(depth_stream)
            depth_array_disp = ((depth_array / 10000.) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
            cv2.imshow(depth_window, np.uint8(depth_array_disp))
            cam_handle.save_frame('depth', depth_array, shot_idx, dir_to_write + str(cam_id + 1))
        shot_idx = shot_idx + 1

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:  # exit on ESC
            break
    print "Stopping camera %d thread..." % (cam_id + 1)
    return

def main():
    # Setup camera threads
    cam_threads = []
    dir_to_write = "some/save/path"
    for cam in range(cam_count):
        cam = (cam + 1) % cam_count
        cv2.namedWindow('RGB' + str(cam))
        cv2.namedWindow('DEPTH' + str(cam))
        one_thread = threading.Thread(target=capture_and_save,
                                      name="CamThread" + str(cam + 1),
                                      args=(cam_cap, cam, dir_to_write,
                                            log_writer,
                                            rgb_stream[cam], depth_stream[cam], io,))
        cam_threads.append(one_thread)
        one_thread.daemon = True
        one_thread.start()

        try:
            while True:
                pass
                # cv2.waitKey(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Stop everything
            for each_thread in cam_threads:
                each_thread.do_run = False
                each_thread.join(1)
            cam_cap.stop_rgb(rgb_stream)
            cam_cap.stop_depth(depth_stream)

            # Stop and quit
            openni2.unload()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, my issue is that if I remove the `cv2.imshow()` lines from the code, everything runs as expected and I get both camera outputs saved to file. However, with the `cv2.imshow()` lines, there are only "blank" windows being created and the threads seem to be "stuck", with no output at all.
I have tried several suggestions, including moving the `namedWindow` creation to the main thread as well as into the `capture_and_save` thread. I have also tried moving around the `waitKey()` because it was said that OpenCV only allows `waitKey()` in the main thread. There was no difference, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the issue by using mutables, passing a dictionary `cam_disp = {}` to the thread and reading the value in the main thread. `cv2.imshow()` works best when kept in the main thread, so this worked perfectly. I am not sure if this is the "right" way to do this, so all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: could you please post the modified code as well , I am just bumping my head since last 5 hours

Comment: @csharpcoder take a look at https://github.com/kanishkaganguly/OpenNIMultiSensorCapture/blob/master/capture_cam.py

I think this is the most updated code, with the changes mentioned above.

Comment: My bad, I just committed the latest working code.
https://github.com/kanishkaganguly/OpenNIMultiSensorCapture/blob/master/capture_tool.py

Comment: Thanks kanishka , will have a look into it.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the modified solution here instead of a link, as [per SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Since - as in this case - the source code seems to have changed and no longer references `cv2.imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `cv2.namedWindow('RGB' + str(cam))` inside your thread target `capture_and_save`

Answer (score 0):

The `cv2.imshow` function is not thread safe.
Just move `cv2.namedWindow` to the `threading.Thread` that calls `cv2.imshow`.

```
import cv2
import threading

def run():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
    cv2.namedWindow("preview", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            print("Video is over")
            break
        cv2.imshow('preview', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    print("Bye :)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, without knowing :) but its the best explanation I have.

When you try to open the image in the view you will pass the image from the camera thread to the GUI-thread. When doing so you will be out of synch. Sometimes it works. I think you will/might end up with the same problem at some point. (I did) It is more noticeable when running more than 1 thread. What you can do is use a thread-safe memory (queue) or a thread lock.

You then put the thread lock around the camera save, in the thread, and imshow read in main you will be safe. There is also the GIL spooking around which you also need to read more about. But easiest is the thread lock in your case but all depends on how much you need to control the flow of data and priority of "reading camera" or showing on screen in "real time". The answer from @DarkSidds is correct too. But if you have more than 1 camera and those are writing from the thread you will crash.