# cv2.imshow() starts without poping up a window when called in threading

Tags: multithreading, opencv, macos-catalina

cv2.imshow() do not pop up the window when called in the threading. An icon of python3 appears in the docker, but no window, no plot. Besides, I need the function of half-duplex communication, thus I cannot just remove threading. How can I correctly show the picture inside threading? Any response is appreciated.

Background: MacOS Catalina, python==3.5, opencv==3.4.2

```
import cv2
import threading

def run():
    # start the camera
    video_reader = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        # collect image
        ret_val, image = video_reader.read()
        cv2.imshow('image', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break  # esc to quit

t = threading.Thread(target=run, name="run")
t.start()
```

Some Warning messages that may help:

```
python3[86286:1964642] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff2fc177f0 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 371
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff2fc14ce1 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1416
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff2fc14753 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2fea8368 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:] + 52
    4   libopencv_highgui.3.4.2.dylib       0x000000010327bee7 cvNamedWindow + 727
    5   libopencv_highgui.3.4.2.dylib       0x000000010327b7a3 cvShowImage + 195
    6   libopencv_highgui.3.4.2.dylib       0x000000010327860d _ZN2cv6imshowERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayE + 477
    7   cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so           0x00000001014f8393 _ZL18pyopencv_cv_imshowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 387
    8   python3                             0x0000000100ca759f PyCFunction_Call + 127
    9   python3                             0x0000000100d6eec7 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18583
    10  python3                             0x0000000100d68faf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 335
    11  python3                             0x0000000100c746aa function_call + 106
    12  python3                             0x0000000100c30b35 PyObject_Call + 69
    13  python3                             0x0000000100d6fc9b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22123
    14  python3                             0x0000000100d6efb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18824
    15  python3                             0x0000000100d6efb8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18824
    16  python3                             0x0000000100d68faf _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 335
    17  python3                             0x0000000100c746aa function_call + 106
    18  python3                             0x0000000100c30b35 PyObject_Call + 69
    19  python3                             0x0000000100c53694 method_call + 148
    20  python3                             0x0000000100c30b35 PyObject_Call + 69
    21  python3                             0x0000000100d77bf4 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 68
    22  python3                             0x0000000100de472a t_bootstrap + 122
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff69e8cd76 _pthread_start + 125
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff69e895d7 thread_start + 15
)
2019-10-14 15:20:27.485 python3[86286:1964642] WARNING: nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.
```

Comment: hi ..  this solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577228/multithreaded-cv2-imshow-in-python-does-not-work

Comment: I ran your exact code with no changes. except that i used a video file inseted of using the camera ,and the code is working perfectly. try doing so and provide the output you get.

Answer (score 5):

Apple only allows native UI functionality to be used on the main thread in macOS and iOS.